# Subtract 2 rows in the same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to subtract two row values from the same column.
Example:  `250-161= 89` and `20-20 = 0`

[image: QueryExample]

```
BrokenQuantityAdjustment
------------------------
    -161.00
     -89.00
     250.00
     -20.00
      20.00
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.SiteID, a.SiteDescription, iv.VendorNumber, iv.VendorName, 
    i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, mrh.DateReceived, mrh.InvoiceDate, 
    mrh.InvoiceNumber, mrh.DocumentNumber, mrh.ReceivingComment, 
    ia.UnitsPerPack, mri.BrokenQuantityAdjusted, 
    ia.BrokenQuantityAdjustment, ia.BasePackCost, ia.Fee
FROM
    AdmSites AS a 
INNER JOIN
    InvManualReceivingHeader AS mrh ON a.AdmSiteID = mrh.AdmSiteId 
INNER JOIN
    InvAdjustments AS ia ON a.AdmSiteID = ia.AdmSiteID 
                         AND mrh.DateReceived = ia.AdjustmentDate 
                         AND mrh.InvoiceNumber = ia.InvoiceNumber 
INNER JOIN
    InvItems AS i ON ia.InvItemID = i.InvItemID 
INNER JOIN
    InvVendors AS iv ON ia.InvVendorID = iv.InvVendorID 
INNER JOIN
    InvManualReceivingItemsAdjustments AS ria ON mrh.DateReceived = ria.DateReceived 
CROSS JOIN
    InvManualReceivingItems AS mri
WHERE
    (mrh.InvoiceNumber = 'deleted')
```

My results should be for this column:

```
BrokenQuantityAdjustment
--------------------------
          89
         -89
          0
```

I am not sure how to get these results

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired results. It's impossible to say without seeing some of your data and what you are after. I suspect you have many rows, but here you are only wanting to subtract two of them, one from the other, which doesn't make much sense (why are we subtracting 20 from 20, or 161 from 250? Why not subtract 20 from 250?) You can use [a site like this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to paste, format, and copy for pasting here (highlight after pasting in stackoverflow and hit the `{}` button to preserve whitespace and line feeds.

Comment: `LAg` and `LEAD` may be handy :)

Comment: I added a image of my query example: QueryExample link.

Comment: Could you post full table data and show your expect result?

Comment: I am sort of new at this so I am figuring out how to post an example of my query results and what I am expecting. I will have that shortly

Comment: Your query results will not help.   We need sample data as it is in the Table(s), and the desired results you are trying to get, and probably an explanation of the logic you want to follow, because I don't understand why 161 should be subtracted from 250, and why should 20 be subtracted from 20.  It seems completely arbitrary based on what you have shown us.

Comment: My query results:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your snapshots and description, I think you can use `sum` with `group by` to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  BrokenQuantityAdjustment int,
  BasePackCost float
);

insert into t values (-161.00,0.1615)
insert into t values (-89.00,0.1618)
insert into t values (250.00,0.1615)
insert into t values (-20.00,0.1616)
insert into t values (20.00,0.1616)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(BrokenQuantityAdjustment)result
FROM T
GROUP BY BasePackCost
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d5e6/8/0)**:

```
| result |
|--------|
|     89 |
|      0 |
|    -89 |
```

---

You can try this

```
;with cte as(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.SiteID, 
        a.SiteDescription, 
        iv.VendorNumber, 
        iv.VendorName, 
        i.StockNumber, 
        i.StockDescription, mrh.DateReceived, mrh.InvoiceDate, 
        mrh.InvoiceNumber, 
        mrh.DocumentNumber, mrh.ReceivingComment, 
        ia.UnitsPerPack, 
        mri.BrokenQuantityAdjusted, 
        ia.BrokenQuantityAdjustment, 
        ia.BasePackCost, 
        ia.Fee
    FROM
        AdmSites AS a 
    INNER JOIN
        InvManualReceivingHeader AS mrh ON a.AdmSiteID = mrh.AdmSiteId 
    INNER JOIN
        InvAdjustments AS ia ON a.AdmSiteID = ia.AdmSiteID 
                             AND mrh.DateReceived = ia.AdjustmentDate 
                             AND mrh.InvoiceNumber = ia.InvoiceNumber 
    INNER JOIN
        InvItems AS i ON ia.InvItemID = i.InvItemID 
    INNER JOIN
        InvVendors AS iv ON ia.InvVendorID = iv.InvVendorID 
    INNER JOIN
        InvManualReceivingItemsAdjustments AS ria ON mrh.DateReceived = ria.DateReceived 
    CROSS JOIN
        InvManualReceivingItems AS mri
    WHERE
        (mrh.InvoiceNumber = 'deleted')
)

select t1.*,t2.result
from cte t1 inner join (
SELECT SUM(BrokenQuantityAdjustment)result,BasePackCost
FROM cte 
GROUP BY BasePackCost
) t2 on t1.BasePackCost = t2.BasePackCost
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I can't group by just BasePackCost I am using several other column names. You can see my query above.

Comment: `T` you can instead of your current query be a subquery @GNell

Comment: That is great but I do need my other columns also

Comment: you need the answers and details you want.
My answer above is the same as what you expected.

Comment: I don't know how to attach what my result are suppose to look like I keep getting an error.

Comment: @GNell Sorry there is a typo, you can try it now

Comment: looks good I will probably have to tweek it. I should only end up with 3 rows .

Comment: @GNell You can mark this answer if that help you :)

Comment: How would I get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the window function of SUM?

For example replace:

```
ia.BrokenQuantityAdjustment
```

By a SUM OVER with a PARTITION:

```
SUM(ia.BrokenQuantityAdjustment) OVER (PARTITION BY ia.BasePackCost, a.SiteID, a.AdmSiteID, ia.AdjustmentDate, ia.InvoiceNumber, ia.BasePackCost) AS BrokenQuantityAdjustment
```

Not too sure which columns should be in the partition though.